# How to find the best ntree and nodesize in randomForest in R, and then calculate RMSE for confusion table as the result?

Tags: r, random-forest

I have two questions related to randomForest in R.

1. How can I find the best values for two arguments: ntree and nodesize? I just put a random number here and sometimes I found a better result. Can I use kind of k-fold cross validation, or if not, what method I can use to find these values?
2. After I ran randomForest function and have the model, I did the prediction and I have a predicted data, then I can make a confusion table like below:

> Predicted        1 2 3
>
> ```
>  Actual   1  4 3 1
>
>           2  2 4 2
>
>           3  3 2 1
> ```

(i.e, there are 4 + 4 + 1 correct predictions)

My question is, given this kind of table, how can I calculate the RMSE (Root Mean Square Error) of the prediction? Of course I can do it manually but I think it is not the best answer.

Thank you very much,

Comment: Look into the `caret` library with `train( method='rf')`.  This provides some reasonable tuning functionality.

Comment: One question per post please.

Comment: Are you trying to do classification or regression?  You are asking for RMSE, but your confusion matrix suggests a categorical outcome.

Comment: Can I see classification (randomForest) as a subtype of regression, but always return integer values? It is not very true I know, but the goal is given a set of input values, we need to predict the output value, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do all of the above with the [mlr package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlr/index.html). The tutorial has detailed sections on [tuning](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/tune/index.html) and [performance measurements](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/performance/index.html). For tuning, you should use [nested resampling](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/nested_resampling/index.html).

Assuming that you have a regression task, it would look something like this:

```
library(mlr)

# define parameters we want to tune -- you may want to adjust the bounds
ps = makeParamSet(
  makeIntegerLearnerParam(id = "ntree", default = 500L, lower = 1L, upper = 1000L),
  makeIntegerLearnerParam(id = "nodesize", default = 1L, lower = 1L, upper = 50L)
)

# random sampling of the configuration space with at most 100 samples
ctrl = makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 100L)

# do a nested 3 fold cross-validation
inner = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 3L)
learner = makeTuneWrapper("regr.randomForest", resampling = inner, par.set = ps,
                          control = ctrl, show.info = FALSE, measures = rmse)

# outer resampling
outer = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 3)
# do the tuning, using the example boston housing task
res = resample(learner, bh.task, resampling = outer, extract = getTuneResult)

# show performance
print(performance(res$pred, measures = rmse))
```

The whole process would look very similar for classification, see the relevant tutorial pages for more details.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, you can select the best parameters via k-fold cross validation. I would recommend not tuning `ntree` and instead just set it relatively high (1500-2000 trees), as overfitting is not a concern with RF and that way you don't have to tune that as a parameter. You can still go ahead and tune `mtry`.
2. There are many different measures for assessing performance of a classfication problem. If you are specifically interested in an RMSE-like measure, you could check out [this CV post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172945/rmse-root-mean-squared-error-for-logistic-models), which discusses the [Brier Score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brier_score) - this is calculated like RMSE, where you use the probability that was forecast and the actual value to get a mean-squared error.

Comment: Hi Tchotchke, how can I automatically tuning ntree and mtry as you said. Currently I have to run a for loop, and of course it is not good.

Comment: As @C8H10N4O2 mentioned above, you can use the `caret` library. There are also ways to run the CV in parallel, but that would likely take a lot of time to set up (and is a little complicated) so may not be worth it for you.